# Have problems using Eclipse project protected by proguard?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've got a source code coded in Eclipse. When I open it in IntelliJ IDEA 11, all comments cannot be displayed, but instead of them I see some odd squares and other strange symbols. Also I receive many odd errors.

The error is: `Error is: unmappable character for encoding UTF8`

When I open the same project in Eclipse, I see no error and all comments are displayed properly.

Could this be because of proguard added some protection? Anyone can guess what can the problem be?

Comment: I think it's more like charset issue on IntelliJ IDEA 11. I don't think proguard will obfuscate your comments. At least it's not doing that in my application.

Comment: @Android-Droid Could be. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Android-Droid Error is: unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Comment: Never used IntelliJ IDEA 11, but I think if you find any settings about charset or something like that, just set the value to UTF-8.

Comment: Verify that correct encoding is set in `Settings` | `File Encodings`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It says: `IDE Encoding: UTF-8` and on the bottom of setting `Autodetect UTF-encoded files` is checked. Do you want me to post a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your files are not in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It may be as the project is from Asian guy. Is there a way to convert them to UTF-8 from IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: IDEA doesn't convert encoding, you should either specify the same encoding as was used by that guy or convert the file externally using `iconv` or some other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well, [files in Eclipse are not encoded in UTF-8 by defaut](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/29511/), you have to tell it to use UTF-8 by default. If you want to convert your file, try using [notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Hope it helps